# Speed up the FFmpeg process time in Android

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to loop video until the sound stops, everything works good but it takes too much time.
if my audio file length is 4 minutes then it takes approx of 4 minutes & the size is also too much, here is my command

```
 String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i",audioFile.getAbsolutePath(),"-filter_complex","movie="+videoFile.getAbsolutePath()+":loop=0,setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)","-c","copy","-y",createdFile.getAbsolutePath()};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see many "encoding with ffmpeg on Android is too slow" questions here. Assuming you're encoding with libx264 add `-preset ultrafast` and `-crf 26` or whatever value looks acceptable to you (see [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)).

Not much else you can do if you want to use software based encoding via ffmpeg & x264. FFmpeg does not yet support MediaCodec hardware encoding as far as I know. It does support MediaCodec video decoding of H.264, HEVC, MPEG-2, MPEG-4, VP8, and VP9, but decoding is not the bottleneck here.

You can try to get x264 to use your CPU capabilities, such as avoiding compiling x264 with `--disable-asm`, but I don't know if that is possible with your hardware.

Note that stream copying (re-muxing) with `-c copy` is not possible when filtering the same stream, so change it to the more specific `-c:a copy` since you are not filtering the audio.

Comment: I face the same issues with ffmpeg on Android (very slow exec). Yet, I can't imagine there's no solution to that matter. Plenty of Android apps offer features that provide video encoding in a super fast way (insta, snapchat...), how do they manage to do that then?

Comment: @GrayFox Encoding via MediaCodec?

Comment: yeah exactly I ended up with that conclusion too. I found a very good repo that uses perfectly the MediaCoder for my purpose https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android

Answer (score 0):

try this query with addition of " "-preset", "ultrafast" into query , .....  String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i",audioFile.getAbsolutePath(),"-preset", "ultrafast","-filter_complex","movie="+videoFile.getAbsolutePath()+":loop=0,setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)","-c","copy","-y",createdFile.getAbsolutePath()};

Comment: `"-preset", "ultrafast"` should be after `-filter_complex`. Also, provide more explanation instead of just answering `Try this` answers. Currently, your answer does not provide more info/context than the answer provided before yours.